# Text of UITextView and UITextField is getting blurred

Tags: uiscrollview, uitextfield, uitextview, cgaffinetransform, uifont

In my project i am dealing with many UITextFields and UITextViews placed on a view which is a subview from a UIScrollview.When the scrollView is zoomed the text in the textView/textField is getting blurred as the UITextField/UITextView gets transformed according to the scrollView.

I tried googling and found few answers in stack overflow and i tried out them but none worked.

Is there any solution to this issue?I am in a great need to overcome that, can someone help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `CGRectIntegral(CGRect rect)` to position the `UITextField` and `UITextView` objects placed in the `UIScrollView`. I suspect that the subviews are being placed at fractions of pixels, causing the blurriness. If you use `CGRectIntegral` the frame of the subviews will always land on a whole pixel.